# The drop-down menu on mobile chat shows incorrect time

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web, timestamps

[image]

As far as I know this happens randomly.
On reloading the page it shows the correct time for the last message sent. I don't think that Stack Exchange existed 17656 days (48.3 years) ago :P

Comment: 17,656 days ago is the UNIX epoch, January 1, 1970. Presumably, they're querying the wrong variable for it.

Comment: Pretty sure its been happening for ages. For some odd reason I can't quite find the pre-existing question tho.